# unable to extend parition to unallocated space to the right of it

Tags: linux, windows-10, partitioning, gparted, easeus-partition-manager

I need to extend an ex4 partition,
I have 43 GB of free space to the right of the it. I am booted to another drive.

What I tried:

- using EaseUS partition master
- using MiniTool partition master
- using DiskGenius
- using GParted from a live OS on a USB stick.

All failed/refused to give the option to extend the partition.

Seems like DiskGenius on Windows 10 booted from another disk is my best attempt and gives the most information. When I resize the partition it gives [image: this]

Probably the most useful bit of info is this screenshot showing the layout of the disk.[image]

Logical(5) is what I want to extend and the free space is to the right of it.

Comment: did u try window's very own disk manager??

Comment: @Emiley it's a Linux ext4 partition so I didn't , EDIT: now I tried , the extend volume button is gray

Comment: and maybe you might need to convert the ext4 to NTFS

Comment: or making the logical as primary...sorry dont know much about linux...not used it since a lot of years

Comment: is this of any help:http://linux-training.be/sysadmin/ch05.html

Comment: Is the filesystem healthy? Probably not. Did you run `fsck` on it? What did the tool say?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski run fsck from where and with what arguments ?

Comment: From any modern Live CD/DVD/USB distro. [How to perform full check of ext4 file system structure?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/347280/108618) Or let the OS on the partition trigger `fsck` during the next reboot.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski ok did it , all seems good with the file system

Comment: Frankly I wouldn't trust any random Windows tool with my Linux partitions. `gparted` from a live distro or even step-by-step `fdisk`/`gdisk`+`resize2fs` would be my choice.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski yeah I got Kubuntu running live from a USB stick with gparted , it doesn't let me extend it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Logical(5)` is a logical partition inside an extended partition, while the free space lies outside of that extended partition.

You need to resize `Extended Partition` to include the free space first, then resize
`Logical(5)`.

Answer (score -3):

> In the normal interface, Linux's fdisk applies alignment constraints to partitions. Which constraints depends on the version of fdisk. Older versions defaulted to cylinder alignment, for compatibility with older operating systems that were incompatible with LBA. When LBA was a little over two decades old, fdisk stopped catering for such ancient systems by default, and instead switched to 1MB alignment, which gives better performance on modern storage media.
>
> In current versions of fdisk, to create partitions with any sector (512B) alignment, you need to first create the partition with the desired end point, then go to the expert menu (x) and use the command  b to adjust the beginning of the partition (this changes the partition size, not where it ends). It does seem rather clumsy.

[Source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/320447)

Comment: Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/320201/how-to-extend-logical-extended-partition-with-fdisk/320378#320378

Comment: No instructions given just irrelevant off-topic information, answer is a copy paste from another question without giving credit to the original author

Comment: @tomerzeitune  I did mention the source ...didn't I ??

Comment: @Kamil Maciorowski Thankyou...I don't know how to make the link go directly to the answer instead of the page ....how to  do it ??

Comment: I edited the answer so it's clear you're *quoting* from elsewhere. Still this is not useful here. It *might* be *somewhat* useful if the OP was trying to extend to the *left*, but in the current situation it's not.

Comment: @Emiley no you did not.

Comment: Click "edit" under the post (or here: [edit]) and see how it's done. You can do this with any question or answer. You can practice without saving changes.

Comment: Oh, the link itself is from the "share" link. Each question/answer has its own "share" button under it.